# MySQL RAND() in WHERE clause matches a small set of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

i get into an interesting issue with MySQL. When i try to multiply RAND() function with some big integer, i get max random number really small. Here is my MySQL query, that should be a very fast random query, but it returns ID max 36000, even when there are 4600000+ IDs.

```
SET @maxID=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM property); #it's about 4600000

SELECT * FROM property
WHERE 
downloaded_at IS NULL
AND id >= FLOOR(1 + RAND() * @maxID) #this returns max +/-36000
LIMIT 100
```

When i move this code into plain SELECT query, everything is fine

```
SELECT FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM property))
```

Could someone please explain, why this error occurs? Thank you!

**edits**

---

Hm, somehow when i remove `downloaded_at IS NULL` it comes to sences, ID's are higher, but results are not that random anymore.

---

I can't use ORDER BY RAND(), because table is too big, query is too slow and whole server crashes eventually in few minutes

---

version is 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Note that since `(SELECT MAX(id) FROM property)` is a static subquery it will be executed only once. So there is no need to use a variable.

Comment: BTW: I would expect `RAND()` to be executed only once.

Comment: RAND() is executed everytime, it's required for my random query, otherwise it will return sequention of rows, not random

Comment: What you do looks clever but also risky, because you just don't know what's going on in the where clause. I would use a more reliable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random row selection method is ***biased***... the probabilty of a row being seleted is proportional to its id. E.g if you had 10 rows with id = 1 to 10 then 1 has 10% chance of being selected, 2 has 20% and so on.

Also, the reason why your code selects ids less than ~36000 is obvious: rows are (usually) processed in PK order and by the time 100th matching row is found, the query has only processed row with id of around 36000.

Now, if you are interested in selecting 100 random rows, you can use this query instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM property
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM property
    WHERE downloaded_at IS NULL
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 100
)
```

Or may be this (rough outline):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM property
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM property
    WHERE RAND() <= 100.0 / @maxID -- explanation below
    LIMIT 100
)
```

The above does not involve sorting but it still needs to scan all ids. `100.0` is same as the desired number of rows but add some more just to be sure. This should result in equal probability for each row to be selected.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention - I can't use RAND() in ORDER BY, because table is too big and it's too slow which eventually leads to run out of memory on server

Comment: @PayteR I looked at your randomization function again and it is somewhat obvious why you get ids less than a certain threshold: rows are usually scanned in order of id and by the time 100th match is found (`LIMIT 100`) the id is somewhere around 36000. `ORDER BY` is better.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting point Salman! It's exactly like that, when i set LIMIT for example to 50, max ID is about 18000. Please edit your answer, write this at top of answer as answer, why it's like that. I will set this answer as correct answer afterwards. Thank you!

Comment: @PayteR see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `rand()` is being called every time the condition in the `where` clause is evaluated.  Instead, put the value in a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM property p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT FLOOR(1 + RAND() * @maxID) as idlim) x
WHERE p.downloaded_at IS NULL AND
      p.id >= x.idlim #this returns max +/-36000
LIMIT 100;
```

This ensures that the `rand()` function is called only once.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon, but i need to execute RAND() everytime, because otherwise results are not random